# Динамические структуры С++

Tags: c++

Я не могу вызвать функции, что должны работать с динамической структурой. Выдает синтаксическую ошибку при вызове самой функции.
Прошу прощения, что не скинул целый код, у меня сейчас есть лишь скриншот его кусочка.

Функция:

```
void print(Hello* head){
   if (head!=NULL)
      cout << head->name << " " << head->name << endl;
      print(head->tail)
   }
   else cout << endl;
}
```

Мейн:

```
int main(){
   Hello H;
   int n;
   cont << "how much ?" << endl;
   cin >> n;
   add(n, H** head);
   print(H* head);
}
```

Comment: Вы что-то странное отдаете в функции `add` и `print`. Например, `print` ожидает указатель на `Hello`, значит, вызывать необходимо так `print(&H)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас какой то странный новый с++

```
print(H* head);
```

такого синтаксиса нет.

```
print(H.head);
```

Подозреваю, что Hello это что то такое

```
struct Hello {
    Hello* tail;
    char* name;
    //....
}
```

Наверно, Вы хотите где то так написать

```
int main(){
   Hello H;
   int n;
   cont << "how much ?" << endl;
   cin >> n;
   add(n, &(H.head)); // Но это может быть опасно! надо смотреть функцию add
   print(H.head);
}
```

но надо смотреть весь код.